# Can't install cURL on Linux Mint

Tags: curl

I am trying to install [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) in order to be able to install the [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) version manager.

I write this:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install curl
```

And get this output:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

*Then* I write this:

> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
>
> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

And then I repeat installing cURL and get this:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Update:

*Output for*

```
 $ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 373 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  curl
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main curl i386 7.21.3-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main curl i386 7.21.3-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.21.3-1ubuntu1.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

-

Update 2:

I am using [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 11 (Rosinka), and I am connected to the Internet.

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo fuser -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock`?

Comment: out puts nothing for sudo fuser -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include i) the specific version of Linux Mint you are using; ii) verify whether you are connected to the internet; iii)

Comment: Done Updated it

Comment: The 404 errors suggest that you're using an outdated version of Linux mint, or at least have outdated entries in your `sources.list`. You're using the Ubuntu natty package repository, which is outdated. If you want to use the natty repository, you'll have to switch to the old-releases archives or better yet, upgrade your Linux distro.

Comment: Seeing that you're using Linux Mint 11, I think you're best off upgrading to Linux Mint 17, which has long term support until 2019, and includes the right package repository URL's.

Comment: How do I upgrade to new version?Install totally new version or can I upgrade it from command line?

Comment: The different methods for upgrading Linux mint to a newer release are discussed in this article: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2

Alternatively, you can change your package repositories in your current Linux mint version to use the old-releases repository, which is outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release.

Upgrading your Linux distribution is recommended over using old-release though.

Answer (score 6):

You are running two separate commands there: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install curl`. The `&&` simply links the two commands, it means "run the 2nd if the first one succeeded. Both of these commands need to be run as the root user and this is done by appending `sudo` to them but you are only running the first with `sudo`, not the second. What you are looking for is

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl
```

In addition, it seems like something else is installing something in the background. Stop any other processes that could be using `dpkg`. Finally, since you are also getting an error about certain index files not being downloaded, remove the `&&`. Instead run:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Although the OP should indeed add sudo to the apt-get upgrade command, the fact that this particular error message is being thrown suggest that the error happens after the apt-get update command. Permission errors should result in a `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?` error, afaik.

Comment: I did this is the output - E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @user2950593 that's fine, what happens if you run `curl`?

Comment: The program 'curl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl

Comment: @user2950593 and when you run `sudo apt-get install curl`, the only output is what you showed above?

Comment: @Shinigami yes, good point. I missed the details of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` uses `dpkg` to install packages.

It looks like another process is using dpkg, make sure that you're not simultaneously installing something from the (GUI) software manager or make sure you aren't upgrading packages in the background.

Comment: I've restarted laptop and repeated -the same situation.

Comment: Use `ps aux | grep dpkg` command in the terminal to see if dpkg is running and what it is doing. If you're not sure, post the output of that command here, that might give us an idea what is going on

Comment: output: 0.0  0.0   4152   860 pts/0    S+   00:31   0:00 grep --colour=auto dpkg